# Rails Devise Gem init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rubygems

I've successfull launched this command for install devise

```
rails generate devise:install
```

Now I have to launch

```
rails generate devise user
```

but console tell me:

```
/Users/hele/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in rescue in spec: Specified mysql2 for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'mysql2' to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
```

In GemFile I have:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails' , '4.2.3'
gem 'devise', '4.1.1'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.3.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you paste your `Gemfile` here

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` since adding mysql2?

Comment: source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails' , '4.2.3'
gem 'devise', '4.1.1'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'font-awesome-rails', '4.3.0.0'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

Comment: @mastro you should add the `gemfile` to question!

Comment: Just inserted into comment. Now past also into question :)

Comment: @mastro you have used both `mysql2` and `sqlite3` !! why so? which db you are using ?

Comment: @dkp I use mysql2.

Comment: @mastro just remove `gem 'sqlite3'` from your `gemfile` and give a try to `gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'` and `bundle install`!

Comment: Hi. Why the presence of sqlite3 should be a problem?
Anyway. 0.3.18 version works! Thanks, you can add your answer!

Comment: @mastro I have added an answer. yes, you can have both `sqlite3` and `mysql2` in your gemfile but `sqlite3` is not required if you are using `mysql` as your db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Rails 4.2.3, give a try to:

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
```